# How to access Django local server data with React-native?

Tags: javascript, python, django, react-native

I build a Django API using django rest framework.
And a want to access the json response data of the api in my react-native app.
But a get an error (**Network request failed**)

**DJANGO RESPONSE**
[image]

**REACT-NATIVE**
[image]

**ERROR**

> Network request failed

- node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:505:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:135:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:387:16 in callTimers
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

- [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Answer (score 2):

Please consider take the following suggestions:

1. activate developer mode on your device and than turn on the "USB Debugging" mode.
2. Plug your device into a USB port on your pc
3. Add this line into your `package.json` file inside the `scripts` object:

   `"android-dev": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081"`
4. Check if CORS is configured in your `settings.py` Django project file and make sure to allow all hosts to access the project (of specify the hosts if that's important to your tests).

   INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'rest_framework',
   'corsheaders',
   ...
   ]

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
   ...
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   ...
   ]

   CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
   ```
5. Check your local ip (usually starts with `192.168...`). Do this by running `ipconfig` on windows or `ifconfig` on linux.
6. Make sure you are running your Django project with the same IP as your local network. For exemple, my local ip is 192.168.15.2, so I run `python manage.py runserver 192.168.15.2:8000`. In my case I like to use Pycharm, so I configure it in the server settings
   [image]
7. And for the last step, use that same IP in your requests adding the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":'*'` in the request header. So it would be something like this:

[image]

Note that I use axios for sending requests, but you can check how add the headers in your request using fetch [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

I wish you the best. This is really a annoying problem that I took some time to figure it out.